# Cutting down a Cherry tree

Tags: trees

Hi I’m trying to ascertain whether I’ll be doing any  damage to my property by cutting a cherry tree down. The tree is approximately 5 meters from the house. I’m not sure of the soil type other than the area is known for its sand, postcode Lu72TY UK

Comment: How tall is it? Is it an edible fruiting cherry or an ornamental one? Are you in a high rainfall/flood risk area?

Comment: Hi it doesn’t bear fruit, it just blossoms in the Spring. It’s around 20 years old, approx 3 meters high. I don’t live in a flood risk area, average rainfall.

Comment: Why do you want to cut it down?

Comment: My neighbour and I have both had our drives extended so there’s no room for the tree to grow without damaging them.

Answer (score 1):

Cutting it down won't cause any damage to your property, well, not unless it falls onto it while you're cutting it down. However, because it's an ornamental cherry tree and likely grafted, it would be best to remove the stump  and  major roots by boring them out rather than just poisoning the stump. If you're getting a professional to cut the tree down, ask them to bore the stump and roots out too - otherwise, you can hire a stump grinder, though they are not that easy to use. Cherry trees have a lot of surface roots, and often produce growth some feet away off the rootstock - this is much more likely to occur if the tree has been cut down.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, we do plan to grind down the stump, so hopefully all will be well.

Comment: I cut down a 30 foot cherry 5 meters from my house two years ago. No problems. Without grinding, mushrooms came up heavily the next year. Stump is about gone. Needed someone with a rope to pull on some upper branches so as to avoid power lines etc. Worst part was, I discovered I was allergic to cherry tree dust/sap. You might want a quick shower as possible protection.